# How reliable is the cost measurement in PostgreSQL Explain Plan?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance, explain, sql-execution-plan

The queries are performed on a large table with 11 million rows. I have already performed an `ANALYZE` on the table prior to the query executions.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts t2 
    ON (t1.account_no = t2.account_no
        AND t1.effective_date < t2.effective_date)
WHERE t2.account_no IS NULL;
```

**Explain Analyze:**

```
Hash Anti Join  (cost=480795.57..1201111.40 rows=7369854 width=292) (actual time=29619.499..115662.111 rows=1977871 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: ((t1.account_no)::text = (t2.account_no)::text)
  Join Filter: ((t1.effective_date)::text < (t2.effective_date)::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on accounts t1  (cost=0.00..342610.81 rows=11054781 width=146) (actual time=0.025..25693.921 rows=11034070 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=342610.81..342610.81 rows=11054781 width=146) (actual time=29612.925..29612.925 rows=11034070 loops=1)
        Buckets: 2097152  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1834187kB
        ->  Seq Scan on accounts t2  (cost=0.00..342610.81 rows=11054781 width=146) (actual time=0.006..22929.635 rows=11034070 loops=1)
Total runtime: 115870.788 ms
```

The estimated cost is **~1.2 million** and the actual time taken is **~1.9 minutes**.

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM accounts t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts t2 
    ON (t1.account_no = t2.account_no
        AND t1.effective_date < t2.effective_date)
WHERE t2.account_no IS NULL;
```

**Explain Analyze:**

```
Hash Anti Join  (cost=480795.57..1201111.40 rows=7369854 width=146) (actual time=13365.808..65519.402 rows=1977871 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: ((t1.account_no)::text = (t2.account_no)::text)
  Join Filter: ((t1.effective_date)::text < (t2.effective_date)::text)
  ->  Seq Scan on accounts t1  (cost=0.00..342610.81 rows=11054781 width=146) (actual time=0.007..5032.778 rows=11034070 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=342610.81..342610.81 rows=11054781 width=18) (actual time=13354.219..13354.219 rows=11034070 loops=1)
        Buckets: 2097152  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 545369kB
        ->  Seq Scan on accounts t2  (cost=0.00..342610.81 rows=11054781 width=18) (actual time=0.011..8964.571 rows=11034070 loops=1)
Total runtime: 65705.707 ms
```

The estimated cost is **~1.2 million (again)** but the actual time taken is **<1.1 minutes**.

**Query 3:**

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE (account_no,
       effective_date) IN
    (SELECT account_no,
            max(effective_date)
     FROM accounts
     GROUP BY account_no);
```

**Explain Analyze:**

```
Nested Loop  (cost=406416.19..502216.84 rows=2763695 width=146) (actual time=31779.457..917543.228 rows=1977871 loops=1)
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=406416.19..406757.45 rows=34126 width=43) (actual time=31774.877..33378.968 rows=1977425 loops=1)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=397884.72..404709.90 rows=341259 width=43) (actual time=27979.226..29841.217 rows=1977425 loops=1)
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=397884.72..401297.31 rows=341259 width=18) (actual time=27979.224..29315.346 rows=1977425 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on accounts  (cost=0.00..342610.81 rows=11054781 width=18) (actual time=0.851..16092.755 rows=11034070 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using accounts_idx2 on accounts  (cost=0.00..2.78 rows=1 width=146) (actual time=0.443..0.445 rows=1 loops=1977425)
        Index Cond: (((account_no)::text = ("ANY_subquery".account_no)::text) AND ((effective_date)::text = "ANY_subquery".max))
Total runtime: 918039.614 ms
```

The estimated cost is **~502,000** but the actual time taken is **~15.3 minutes!**

- How reliable is the `EXPLAIN` output?
- Do we always have to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see how our query is going to perform on real data, and **not place trust** on how much the query planner *thinks* it will cost?

Comment: Cost is an arbitrary number. Costs are only relative to each other, they have no units and no external meaning. You could estimate a rough conversion factor from query cost to execution time for your machine by comparing cost estimate to execution time for a bunch of queries, but that's about the only way. The reliability of cost estimates is based largely on how good a job the planner does, how up to date and detailed your table stats are, and whether you're encountering any known cost-estimation issues like correlated columns.

Comment: _"You could estimate a rough conversion factor from query cost to execution time for your machine by comparing cost estimate to execution time for a bunch of queries"_ That rough conversion factor is totally useless in the above case. If I roughly estimate the cost to time conversion factor of queries 1 and 2, I would think the query 3 shouldn't take more than 45 seconds. **But it takes more than 15 minutes? Why?**

Comment: In other words, the cost appears to be highly misleading. If I trusted the cost, I would have picked query 3 over query 2, but the actual execution time shows that I should really be picking query 2 over query 3.

Comment: Planner's certainly mis-estimating that one. Hard to say why w/o more digging. Rowcount estimates are sane (see http://explain.depesz.com/s/4Jn). Looks like the index scan is taking *way* longer than Pg expects it to. `random_page_cost` too low to reflect reality? Things like this need some digging I'm afraid.

Comment: So costs aren't really a good estimate of query execution time. Not least because being within a factor of 10 or so is generally considered pretty good. They're planner cost parameters, for comparing alternative plans, and that's about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are reliable, except for when they are not.  You can't really generalize.

It looks like it is dramatically underestimating the number of different account_no that it will find (thinks it will find 34126 actually found 1977425).  Your default_statistics_target might not be high enough to get a good estimate for this column.

Comment: That's a good tip! I guess one of the clues for when the estimate is bad is when the number of rows estimated does not come close enough to the actual number of rows.

Comment: "They are reliable, except for when they are not. You can't really generalize." This line is pretty helpful! I wonder, how this answer even got accepted.